# truffle run verify SomeContractName --network bscTestnet not working

Tags: verify, bsc

I followed the instructions:
https://docs.bnbchain.org/docs/truffle-new/

Could already deploy the SmartContract and migrate to bscTestnet, but verifying with the plugin truffle-pluging-verify is not working. I get the following error message:

TypeError: (intermediate value).hostname.split(...).at is not a function
at getApiKey (/home/hakikat/SoupTokenterm/node_modules/truffle-plugin-verify/dist/util.js:141:58)
at /home/hakikat/SoupTokenterm/node_modules/truffle-plugin-verify/dist/verify.js:92:41
at Generator.next ()
at fulfilled (/home/hakikat/SoupTokenterm/node_modules/truffle-plugin-verify/dist/verify.js:5:58)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
Truffle v5.5.21 (core: 5.5.21)
Node v12.22.9

I don't know what is the problem here. Can please someone help. I installed all modules.